# Spring read property file outside the class path

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a property file located in tomcat folder.Im trying to read the propert file content as follow.but im getting null value for the property value.

file path has no any issue.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.sakaiproject.log.api")
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = {
        "file:/home/tomcat-sakai-7.0.55/sakai/local.properties",
        "file:/home/tomcat-sakai-7.0.55/sakai/sakai.properties" })
public class SpringCryptoContext {



    @Value("${aes.encryption.cipherString}")
    private static String cyperString;

    public SpringCryptoContext() {

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                SpringCryptoContext.class);


        System.out.println(cyperString);


    }
}
```

Edit:

I created seperate class and load the properties as follow.

```
@Service
@PropertySource(name = "locations", value = {
        "file:/home/nirmala/projects/iml/tomcat-sakai-7.0.55/sakai/local.properties",
        "file:/home/nirmala/projects/iml/tomcat-sakai-7.0.55/sakai/sakai.properties" })
public class CryptoToolImpl implements CryptoTool {

    private Cipher cipher = null;
    private Key key = null;
    @Value("${pii.encryption.cipherString}")
    private String cipherString = "";

    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CryptoToolImpl.class);

    public IMLCryptoToolImpl() {
        try {
            fixKeyLength();


            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherString);
            key = KMSKeyStoreSingleton.getInstance().getPrivateKey();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in initializing CryptoToolImpl : "
                    + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

but i get the following error

> Error in initializing CryptoToolImpl : Invalid transformation format:

Comment: Are you sure that the user, tomcat is running with, have read access to the file?

Comment: @ Evgeni Dimitrov yes files have read access

Comment: You cannot use `@Value` on a `static` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following bean in your configuration class:-

```
//To resolve values using the @Value
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

**Update**

static won't work in this case, you need to do the following:-

Add the following code:-

```
@Value("${aes.encryption.cipherString}")
private String cyperString;

public String getCypherString(){
    return this.cyperString;
}
```

This is just an example, but static you are using because you are accessing it in the `main method` which is `static` and for accessing the variable, you marked it `static`

The issue is that the static variable is a class variable which is having no property when the code reaches at your line of `System.out` for the variable, At this time - spring is still doing internal initialization etc..

You are accessing/ using the variable as non spring framework while you are instantiating using spring. It has to be single way only

And I would suggest to have a separate class to load these variables into context, may be some class marked with `@Component` or more specifically `@Service`

Comment: still getting null.

Comment: can you check spellings of your property's key

Comment: No issues with the file path and property key

Comment: I read all articles related to spring property file reading.In all those articles property file is defined in the class path of the project.

Comment: @ kakabali still getting null

Comment: share updated code, and please try to get the exact things like application context etc,

Comment: you are accessing/ using the variable as non spring framework while you are instantiating using spring. It has to be single way only

Comment: new question should have been better? share more error logs

Answer (score 1):

Something below should help.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value={
    @PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/sakai/local.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/sakai/sakai.properties")
})
public class SpringCryptoContext {

    @Value("${aes.encryption.cipherString}")
    private String cyperString;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146744/spring-catalina-home-on-property-source-path-giving-a-error