# Spring ${catalina.home} on property source path giving a error

Tags: spring

Im trying to refer ${catalina.home} environment variable on property source path in spring as follow

```
Configuration
@PropertySources(value={
    @PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/sakai/local.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value="file:${catalina.home}/sakai/sakai.properties")
})
public class SpringCryptoContext {

    @Value("${aes.encryption.cipherString}")
    private String cyperString;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigDev() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
        return placeholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

but it gives following error stacktrace

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve
>   placeholder 'catalina.home' in string value
>   "file:${catalina.home}/sakai/local.properties"    at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:359)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:255)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:168)
>     ... 8 more

Comment: it seems your code have some typo issues.  How does this works ?PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new

Comment: Do you have catalina.home in your system properties. The variable is auto refererred from tomcat build.xml file

Comment: @ Sangam Belose no typo issue.sorry object create part is missing when pasting.

Comment: what is the spring and tomcat version you are using?

Comment: @ Sangam Belose tomcat 7 and spring 4.6.2

Comment: I dont see any issues in the given code. May be your property value is getting overriden by some other source